# Accessing h2 database from specified path

Tags: java, database, h2

How do I access an H2 database from a specified file path say E:\folder\mydb.h2.db  in java? What would be the jdbc url for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an example code from the [H2DB tutorial site](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a)
            throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
            getConnection("jdbc:h2:E:\\folder\\mydb", "sa", "");
        // add application code here
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use XML based configuration

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
```